# How to direct one logging to one file and rest to other in python with filtering

Tags: python, logging

I have been googling since quite time to separate out selenium log (Automation API) debug info  with application (My logging info) in two different file but automation api log is also coming on my application log file.

I tried following approach (I tried commented line too):

```
def get_selenium_logger():
  logger=logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection')
  fh = logging.FileHandler('results/selenium_log.log', delay=True)
  fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  logger.addHandler(fh)

  return logger

def get_application_logger():
  logger=logging.getLogger()
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
  fh = logging.FileHandler('results/automation_log.log', delay=True)
  fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  formatter=logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(module)s - %(funcName)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s')
  fh.setFormatter(formatter)  
  #logger.removeFilter(logging.Filter('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection'))
  logger.addHandler(fh)
  return logger

def my_automation_code():
  get_selenium_logger()
  app_logger = get_application_logger()
  app_logger.info("Test **************")
```

debug log from automation api (selenium) also listed on "automation_log.log", How can I filter it?

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the root logger for your application, using a logger whose name doesn't start with "selenium." to separate the two logs. For example:

```
def get_application_logger():
  logger=logging.getLogger('myapp')
  # rest of the stuff as in your snippet
```

**Update:** The name of your application is whatever you decide. In a module which is imported, you can use `__name__` as the logger name; in a script, it can be whatever you like, e.g. the basename of the script.

Comment: Thanks for detail.  It my sound weird but can you please let me know how to find out name of my app? I have root folder name and then one starting point as app_runner.py.

Comment: or we do have some kind of "." or "this" or getApp() method for it?